# SDK/API to use in 24-48 hours game development competition

Tags: framework, game-development

I participate in a lot of programming competition and mostly game development competitions. We have a limited time to create a game in a team of 2-4 people. I was wondering, what might be the best SDK (or API) to use in those kind of fast pace development?

There is no time to create a grandiose game, the point is just to create a small, addictive, original game in less than 2 days. Most of the time, we build our game from scratch, which is not productive because taking time on core mechanics takes a lot of time off polishing and adding useless stuff that users like, like achievements, bonuses, secret levels, etc.

Now I'm not looking for ONE absolute solution, I just want to know what could be interesting. I develop as much in C# as in C++ or Java, but lately kind of focused on C# for those competitions.

Comment: Do you have any requirements of what mechanics it supports?

Comment: Sounds like you want an engine, such as Flash or Unity.  Then you build the game on top of that engine.

Comment: I don't have requirements, but since it could be cool to publish it afterwards (without paying anything), windows or android would be nice :P